# Uniqueness of Linear Differential Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Suppose that Y is a n-dimensional vector. Consider the following linear differential equation system

$$dY/dt=AY$$

$$Y(0)=y_0$$

In which A is an n by n matrix.

My question is, can there be two different matrix A and B, such that $dY/dt=AY$ and $dY/dt=BY$ gives the same solution given the same initial condition? Or, I think that it is equivalent, can $exp(A*Y)$and $exp(B*Y)$ be the same when the exponential is defined as taylor series expansion?

If this problem is too complex, a link to papers would be enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that the solutions correspond for **all** initial conditions?

Comment: The two differential equation should have the same initial condition (or I will not assume that they have the same solution), though I pose no restriction on what kind of initial condition it is. Thank you!

Comment: Since the systems are linear, you only need to consider $n$ linearly independent initial conditions. A convenient set are the standard unit vectors, see the answer below.

Comment: WOW that's smart...Thank you!

Comment: Not me, it is standard linear systems stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix differential equations $\dot{X} = AX$, $X(0) = I$ has solution $X(t) = e^{At}$.

If $A,B$ are such that $e^{At} = e^{Bt}$ for all $t$, then differentiating and setting $t=0$ gives $A=B$.